# Unable to Initialize AdMob in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, build, admob, settings

I'm working on a critical patch for an Android game. The game got removed from Google Play because of out-of-date SDKs. I also switched from Unity Ads to Google AdMob using the Google Mobile Ads Unity Plugin. I got everything set up in AdMob (at least I think I did) and imported the latest package. I wrote this code for initializing the package:
`private void InitAds() { MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { }); }`

This is my initialization code that calls the InitAds function:

```
private async void Init()
{
    try
    {
        var options = new InitializationOptions().SetEnvironmentName("development");

        await UnityServices.InitializeAsync(options);

        if(UnityServices.State == ServicesInitializationState.Initialized)
        {
            InitAds();
            InitIAP();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        Debug.LogError("MoneyManager:Init() - Unity Gaming Services failed to initialize. Exception info: \n" +
            "Message: " + exception.Message +
            "\n Source: " + exception.Source +
            "\n Stack Trace: " + exception.StackTrace +
            "\n Help: " + exception.HelpLink);
    }
}
private void InitAds()
{
    MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });
}
```

However, when I run it in a build in Android Studio, I get this error when it tries to initialize:

`Exception info: Message: The type initializer for 'GoogleMobileAds.Android.MobileAdsClient' threw an exception. Source: GoogleMobileAds.Android Stack Trace: at GoogleMobileAds.GoogleMobileAdsClientFactory.MobileAdsInstance () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 at GoogleMobileAds.Api.MobileAds..ctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 at GoogleMobileAds.Api.MobileAds.get_Instance () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 at GoogleMobileAds.Api.MobileAds.Initialize (System.Action\1[T] initCompleteAction) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0at MoneyManager.Init () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 at System.R` 
I've tried everything from changing managed code stripping to resolving Android dependencies, but still can't find a solution.

My environment:
Unity version: 2023.1.10f1
AdMob package version: 8.5.2
Android version: 8.1
Editor OS: macOS Ventura 13.6

What I've tried so far:

- Resolving Android library dependencies
- Changing managed code stripping settings
- Made sure AdMob dashboard was configured correctly
- Changed Minify settings
- Added custom Proguard text file
- Clean build in Android Studio

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.